# Python move files older than 7 days but keep the most recent ones

Tags: python, list

I need to find files older than 7 days and move them but make sure I do not move all the files. so keep at least a certain number of files (the x most recent ones) on disk. (even if they are older than 7 days)

the purpose is to keep the directory clean but always have a recent backup available in case a quick rollback is needed.

I have used this to find and sort the files.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import re
import time
import shutil

now = time.time()

outputlist = []

regexp='sudoers\.(?!rpm).*'

regex = re.compile(regexp)
dir = '/etc'
filenames = os.listdir(dir)
for filename in filenames:
    abspath = os.path.join(dir, filename)
    if regex.findall(abspath):
       if os.path.isfile(abspath):
          if os.path.getctime(abspath) < now - 7 * 86400:
              print (abspath, os.path.getctime(abspath))
              outputlist.append(abspath)
outputlist.sort(key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
for xfiles in outputlist:
    shutil.move(xfiles, '/opt/backup')
```

the outputlist is normally sorted by ctime in reverse order meaning newest file first.
How can i skip the first 'x' elements of the list and move from the x+1 element?
in my example above it removes all the files older than 7 days found i want to skip per instance the 5 newest file found and do not remove those.

Comment: `outputlist[x+1:]`?

Comment: what if the files found in outputlist < x +1 example if x = 10 so i want to keep at least 10 files on disk. but only 7 files are found older than 7 days.. i will then have nothing to move! how do i tell shutil there is nothing to move?

Comment: Hi.  Could you use something like `rsync` for this?

Comment: What do you use the regex for? Is it to check if the owner is administrator?

Comment: `outputlist[x+1:]` is an empty list if `x` is less than the list's size. You could have easily tried and found out.

Comment: You mention `shutil`, but you don't show what part of `shutil` you use, so I can't answer that question. But if you run the relevant command in a loop, looping over the list above will work; and if the list is empty, nothing happens, because the loop simply runs zero times.

Comment: Note that there are tools to do this. So unless this is a learning exercise, you'll be better off using such tools for backing up data. `rsync` is one of them (can be combined with e.g. `cron`), but there are ones that provide extra extra functionality over the `rsync` + `cron` combo. Search around.

Comment: this is not a learning exercice, it is  script i want to feed to  ansible script module that will move the backups from /etc to a backup location if it was an one off operation rsync would do the trick. But i do not think rsync can take the constrainst in consideration: 
files older than 7 days and keep at least x files on /etc even if they are older than 7 days..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how I would do it.

```py
from re import match
from os import listdir, remove
from os.path import getctime, isfile
from datetime import timedelta, datetime as dt

def time_validator(days):
    delta = dt.now() - timedelta(days)
    return lambda x: dt.fromtimestamp(getctime(x)) > delta

def files_to_remove(n):
    validate = time_validator(7)
    files = sorted([
        y for x in listdir('/etc')
        if isfile((y := f'/etc/{x}'))
        and validate(y)
        and match('sudoers\.(?!rpm).*', y)
    ], key=lambda x: getctime(x))
    return files[-n:] if len(files) > 20 else []

def remove_files(files):
    for file in files: remove(file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_files(files_to_remove(10))
```

Comment: the regex is used to find which files to remove. in my example i want to move all the files that start with sudoers and have an extension eg `sudoers.xxx` but do not remove the files with .rpmsave/.rpmnew'
also from the files found do not remove the x newest files from disk.. eg : if there are 20 backups found older than 7 days then do not remove the x newest ones per instance the 10 newest files.

Comment: this is not to backup files.. it to remove backups made on /etc by a tool that deploys files and does a backup before replacing.

Comment: I don't understand why you would remove the newest backups and also why you are storing backups on the `/etc` directory.

Comment: the sudoers are being deployed by ansible. ansible creates backup of the files in the same directory  . and as i said i do not want to remove the newest backup i just want to remove  those older backups but keep a few recent files on disk in case a rollback is needed. 
this script will also used by ansible to do the cleanup in 100's of hosts. our infra could use ipa and other more adecuate tools but this is what it is :( thanks

Comment: Ah i just understood that you wanted to delete recent backups when you wrote `eg : if there are 20 backups found older than 7 days then do not remove the x newest ones per instance the 10 newest files. ` 
Ill change the code to remove the oldest then :)

Comment: btw if `n` is larger than 20 you will get a problem

Comment: `n` should be any length.  it depends how many files matching the pattern and older of seven days are found.  but you already helped me enough. i guess i will check slicing to skip the first few item on the sorted list and move/delete the rest.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to skip per instance the 5 newest files found and do not remove those

```
for filename in filenames[5:]:
```